# Url rewrite issue if a-Tag is used like a button

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, iis

I have an IIS-Webserver and a Fortinet router that is used in reverse proxy mode.

So the problem is, if I use a-Tags like buttons like this

```
<a onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$detail$245','')" href="#">Click me</a>
```

they are rewritten in this

```
<a onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$detail$245','')" href="https://255.255.255.255/proxy/http/200.200.200.200/Websites/Server/Gui/TestFolder/#">Click me</a>
```

where 255.255.255.255 is my fortinet IP and 200.200.200.200 is my webserver IP. Gui/TestFolder is the current path of my page.

The strange thing is after a postback the href is changed to href="#" like before.

I have alot of these links in my webserver, so changing all to something else would be no solution.

Comment: You need to return false to NOT follow the link  `onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$detail$245',''); return false"` - it does not matter what the URL is unless you want to postback AND follow the link

Comment: Why dont you use linkbutton?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Return false is right, didn't get it ... i knew that the thing with a linkbutton will work,but it is a lagre project. So both good solutions, but I am searching for a solution that has not to mean that I have to change every part of my code wehre this situation is...

Comment: Another question to that: Is it possible that the IIS is loosing my page? Because the href-attribute gets only the path infront of the '#', normaly it schould look like: `"https://255.255.255.255/proxy/http/200.200.200.200/Websites/Server/Gui/TestFolder/MyPage.aspx#"` and not `"https://255.255.255.255/proxy/http/200.200.200.200/Websites/Server/Gui/TestFolder/#`